# Drop-Down Menu with jQuery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

why `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` does not work true on my menu?
They are repeated several times with `mouseover()`.

see you: [jsfiddle-my codes](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgczz/)

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the ul:

```
#nav ul {
    display: none;
```

But you want to slide in the li inside the ul:

```
$('#nav li ul li').slideDown();
```

Therefore,

```
$('#nav li ul').slideDown();
```

works fine.